# Running a program using the Ubuntu OS

Tags: 20.04

I have a problem which I am hoping someone will help me understand 
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 operating system.
I am trying to run a program that is designed to run on Ubuntu but when I try to install the program I get errors during the installation process so I got in touch with the company that made the program only to be told the program will only run on an x86 processor and not on an ARM 64 processor.

I would have thought that if a program was capable of running on the Ubuntu operating system then it should run on any platform that is running Ubuntu whether it be PC or Mac or Raspberry Pi?

Am I wrong in this assumption? And although a program is being said to be able to run on Ubuntu still depends on the underlying processor?

In other words, I can only run programs that use the Ubuntu operating system but I must also check it will run with a particular processor and not assume like in windows I can run any programs that are designed to run on that particular version of Windows regardless of the processor that’s is running the Windows operating system

Clarity on this issue would be welcomed

Comment: That `if a program was capable of running on the Ubuntu operating system then it should run on any platform that is running Ubuntu wether it be PC or Mac or Raspberry P` is just wrong. It depends on the program. Windows doesn't run on arm ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I would have thought that if a program was capable of running on the Ubuntu operating system then it should run on any platform that is running Ubuntu wether it be PC or Mac or Raspberry Pi ?

No. Well not exactly no. It can run but you need to find the source and compile it for that platform. And it might need editing source files to get it to work as intended.

> Am I wrong in this assumption?

Yes, it is called architecture and there are 2 main: amd64 (or x64 or 64-bit) and arm. We used to also have i386 (or x86 or 32 bit) but that got phased out (a few others are MIPS, Power ISA (IBM), SPARC (SUN), Itanium (HP) but those are not really found on consumer hardware). Newer Ubuntu can no longer be installed on 32-bit platforms though 32-bit software can run on a 64-bit machine.

> but I must also check it will run with a particular processor

Inside the OS itself installation of software is done for that type of architecture unless you tell it to pick another architecture. Personal downloads though should be with the architecture in mind. arm software does not run on amd and amd software does not run on arm.

> and not assume like in windows I can run any programs that is designed to run on that particular version of windows regardless of the processor that’s is runing the windows operating system Clarity on this issue would be welcomed

Not true. It is the hardware that is important. An amd64 machine will not run arm software regardless of the operating system. To run such software you need to download the source and then compile that for the architecture you need.

> I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 operating system

You need ARM for that.

[Interesting read](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/raspberry-pi-eben-upton-ama,6206-2.html):

> Q: Why do you use ARM processors and not an x86 processor like Intel? Why not partner with AMD? Ryzen on Raspberry!
>
> A: It's an interesting idea, primarily because it would allow us to run "regular" Windows. But that's less useful than it once was, and the power/price/performance/area advantages of the ARM architecture are pretty convincing.

Comment: Thank you that was was a very informative answer